Reading Dates from Google Sheets in Apps Script
I have two google sheets.
Sheet1 has data as follows:



Column A
Column B




A
27/03/2024


A
24/03/2024



The dates ( Column B ) are gotten by using a VLOOKUP formula.
In Sheet2, I am using QUERY function to aggregate data as follows: QUERY(Sheet1!A:B, "Select A, MIN(B) GROUP BY A"). The resulting data as it is shown in Sheet2:



Column A
min(Column B)




A
24/03/2024



Finally, I am trying to read the data from Sheet2 using Apps Script as follows;
let data = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) // Start from i = 1 to ignore headers
{
    let row = data[i];
    Logger.log(row);
}


The problem I am facing is as follows:
When I am looking at Sheet2 in Google Sheets, the dates looks okay. But when I am reading the same data in apps script, the date gets set to 31 Dec, 9999. Could someone explain why this might be happening, and what can I do to remedy it?
I want to read the dates in apps script as Date object. Right now, they are being read as Date object but they are being set to Dec 31, 9999, when in fact they are different. I tried using getValues, getDisplayValues, etc.
The timezone for the sheet and the script are also same.
One possibly helpful thing:
When I refreshed the sheet, for a brief moment all the dates were Dec 31, 9999. Is it possible that when apps script is reading the data, it is reading before Sheets evaluates it, which is why I am getting the date as 31 Dec, 9999. If so, what can I do to get around this?
Thanks a lot!

Since your dates are not in a form that the constructor recognizes you may have to split then on / into day, month and year to populate the constructor as new Date(year, month - 1,day)

Thanks a lot! I used getDisplayValues() along with what you suggested and it solved the issue.
